# Control Zoom Time on ios MapView

Tags: ios, mapkit

The MKMapKit zoom animation is great and all but it always takes a predefined moment of time to complete the action, that is to say, I as a programmer, have no way of setting a custom time for it to zoom into a particular location.

I've tried throwing the setRegion function inside animation blocks but that doesn't work, the zoom just takes the same amount of time either way. How do you set a custom zoom time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your Problem is [`Nstimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NSTimerExampleViewController : UIViewController {
    NSTimer *aTimer;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "NSTimerExampleViewController.h"

    @implementation NSTimerExampleViewController

    -(void)timerFired:(NSTimer *) theTimer
    {    
        NSLog(@"timerFired @ %@", [theTimer fireDate]);
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        //This starts the Timer
        aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(timerFired:) 
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                 repeats:YES];

    }
```

Comment: [aTimer invalidate]; This stops an NSTimer

Comment: So just zoom to different levels everytime the timer fires?

Comment: Yes the code will zoom in only after whatever time you set it.

Comment: Create couple of timers so after one goes off its zoom in a little more.

Comment: Sweet dude thanks. It's a shame that apple doesn't just let you control the zoom time yourself.

Comment: scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 You change the time here

Comment: Haha yeah but it'd be super nice if apple made functionality to allow you to control the zoom time like 
    [mapView setRegion:location animated:YES withTime:10.0];